# Passing value from HTML form to php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to pass a value from an HTML form and store it to a php variable so i can use this variable into a query to determine what row to get from database. I'm using _post['category'] to get the selected value and I'm passing the variable to the query to get the desired row but I'm not getting anything so far any help will be appreciated. Here is what I wrote so far:

```
<form method="post" action="a34.php">                                                                    
 <select name="category">
  <option value="6008">15</option>
  <option value="6018">25</option>
  <option value="6034">30</option>
  <option value="6038">40</option>





$V=$_POST['category'];

$getrow= "SELECT ProdID, 
ProdCatID, ID_AC_seperate, ProdImage,
 ProdName, ProdPrice, ProdShippingPrice, 
ProdShortDesc, ProdMediumDesc, suitable, 
cart_thumb FROM accessories WHERE ProdID = '$V'";
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! – [Jay Blanchard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard)

Comment: are you submitting your form? and/or is all that code in one script?

Comment: @Little Bobby I know I'm just trying to get to work for now. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jeff it's actually in one script

Comment: and my first question? "are you submitting your form"?

Comment: Do you have in your real script proper `<?php` tags?

Comment: @jeff Yes they are wrapped with php tags

Comment: @jeff so when I set a ProdID in the query it actually works perfect but when I'm trying to pass the ProdID from a from it does nothing

Comment: @user8237728 When do you want the data returned? Immediately upon a user selecting a value or after the form is submitted?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant 'form @jeff

Comment: I want it to be submitted when the user selects an option from the drop down menu @ChrisHappy

Comment: Do you want it onchange of the select element? without a post you will likely need to issue some ajax call. are you already using jQuery?

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery to solve your problem?

Comment: @ChrisHappy Yes I'm open to any suggestion that will make it work

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `strip_tags` function. Never put raw data into sql.

So

```
If(isset($_POST['category']) {
    $data = strip_tags ($_POST['category']);

    $getrow= "SELECT ProdID, ProdCatID, ID_AC_seperate, ProdImage,
                     ProdName, ProdPrice, ProdShippingPrice, 
                     ProdShortDesc, ProdMediumDesc, suitable, cart_thumb
              FROM accessories 
              WHERE ProdID = '. $data .'";
}
```

Comment: I used it but I'm still facing the same problem @Bluesky

Comment: Stupid question did you used: <button type="submit">Send</button>

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try the following.

The JS file detects when the user clicks an option and sends out an ajax request to the updateRow.php file with the `$_POST` variable of `val`.

`updateRow.php` takes the `$_POST` variable and casts it into an integer. The query is then updated with that variable. Process the query, then `echo`, `print`, etc. the data in the desired HTML format. Otherwise, the data echo 'failure'.

The output that is echoed, printed, etc is then sent back to the JS file under the variable `data`. If the data equals 'failure', then an error message is outputted. Otherwise, it inserts the HTML in the `#row` element.

```
// ------ Your JS file ---------

$(function() {
  $row = $("#row");

  $("#update-row").on("change", function() {
    var val = $("select option:selected", this).val();
    $.post('updateRow.php', {
      val: val
    }, function(data) {
      if (data == 'failure') {
        $row.text("Sorry, the row does not exist");
      } else {
        $row.html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
//------- updateRow.php ---------
//Make sure path/to/updateRow.php in the JS file is updated to here

$V = (int) $_POST['val'];

$getrow = "SELECT ProdID, 
ProdCatID, ID_AC_seperate, ProdImage,
ProdName, ProdPrice, ProdShippingPrice,
ProdShortDesc, ProdMediumDesc, suitable,
cart_thumb FROM accessories WHERE ProdID =" . $V;

if ( QUERY_IS_SUCCESSFUL() ) {
  echo 'The <b>HTML</b> you want to display the data in';
} else {
  echo 'failure';
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML file ---->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/js/file.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="a34.php" id="update-row">
  <select name="category">
    <option value="6008">15</option>
    <option value="6018">25</option>
    <option value="6034">30</option>
    <option value="6038">40</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example see for this and then change your code as well accordingly

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // collect value of input field
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  if (empty($name)) {
    echo "Name is empty";
  } else {
    echo $name;
  }
}
?>
```